# Get HTML content between 2 elements

Tags: php, html, tags, element

I need to make a PDF generator using TCPDF and PHP. I could just write everything on the PDF, but that would look awful. Therefore, I need to get every product in the HTML on a different page.

With the newer pages, it's pretty easy. Just use dom document to find the `<div>` around the products, put it in an array and write that to the PDF.

Unfortunately, not every page is the same, so not every page has `<div>`. This page for example.

```
'<h3>sample#1</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
<img>
<table>
</table>

<h3>sample#2</h3>
<p>Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
<img>
<table>
</table>

<h3>sample#3</h3>
<p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
<img>
<table>
</table>

<h3>sample#4</h3>
<p>Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</p>
<img>
<table>
</table>'
```

So what I'm trying to get, is something like this:

```
array (size=4)
0 => string "
<h3>sample#1</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
<img>
<table>
</table>"
1=> string "
<h3>sample#2</h3>
<p>Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
<img>
<table>
</table>"
```

etc.

I have no problem with including something into the server files if needed, but preferably not.

Comment: If you know all the possibilities to how the page may look, you could  use regular expression to extract exactly the data you need in all the cases...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the pages really look like your given example, you can try a simple [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). If the structure of some pages is different from you example, you can adjust your regular expression. [Here](https://www.functions-online.com/preg_match_all.html) is a good site to test the function.

```
$html = '<h3>sample#1</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
<img>
<table>
</table>

<h3>sample#2</h3>
<p>Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
<img>
<table>
</table>

<h3>sample#3</h3>
<p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
<img>
<table>
</table>

<h3>sample#4</h3>
<p>Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</p>
<img>
<table>
</table>';


$matches = array();
$elements = array();

preg_match_all( "#<h3>.*?</table>#s" , $html, $matches );

if( count( $matches[0] ) > 1 ) {
    $elements = $matches[0];
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $elements );
```

OUTPUT:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(105) "<h3>sample#1</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
<img>
<table>
</table>"
  [1]=>
  string(95) "<h3>sample#2</h3>
<p>Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
<img>
<table>
</table>"
  [2]=>
  string(133) "<h3>sample#3</h3>
<p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
<img>
<table>
</table>"
  [3]=>
  string(116) "<h3>sample#4</h3>
<p>Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</p>
<img>
<table>
</table>"
}
```

Comment: you're welcome, I just edited the answer and added a link, where you can test, if some pages differ from your example